# String aligning using .rjust() inside list comprehension - formatting work not as expected

Tags: python, string, list, formatting, alignment

So, I've got this code:

```
def pairwiseScore(seqA, seqB):

    score = 0
    length = len(seqA)
    similarity = []

    for x in xrange(length):

        if seqA[x] == seqB[x]:
            if (x >= 1) and (seqA[x - 1] == seqB[x - 1]):
                score += 3
                similarity.append(x)
            else:
                score += 1
                similarity.append(x)                
        else:
            score -= 1

    return ''.join((seqA, '\n', ''.join(['|'.rjust(x) for x in similarity]), '\n', seqB, '\n', 'Score: ', str(score)))
```

Which is intended to be the solution for [this exercise](http://www.pyschools.com/quiz/view_question/s3-q11).

It works almost good, but, when I execute:

```
print pairwiseScore("ATTCGT", "ATCTAT"), '\n', '\n', pairwiseScore("GATAAATCTGGTCT", "CATTCATCATGCAA")
```

I get this output:

```
ATTCGT
||    |
ATCTAT
Score: 2 

GATAAATCTGGTCT
| |    |     |      |         |
CATTCATCATGCAA
Score: 4
```

So as you can see, those pipes *(or vertical bars)* aren't well formatted.

It should look like this:

```
>>> print pairwiseScore("ATTCGT", "ATCTAT")
ATTCGT
||   |
ATCTAT
Score: 2 
>>> print pairwiseScore("GATAAATCTGGTCT", "CATTCATCATGCAA")
GATAAATCTGGTCT
||  |||  |   
CATTCATCATGCAA
Score: 4 
>>>
```

#### My question is:

What's wrong with this:

```
''.join(['|'.rjust(x) for x in similarity]
```

function? How I have to edit it, to make those pipes well formatted on output?
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Your similarity values are the absolute positions for the bars, but the way you are using the rjust() function, it should be passed the position relative to the previous position.

For example, you could do this at the bottom of your function:

```
prev = -1
relative_similarity=[]
for x in similarity:
  relative_similarity.append(x-prev)
  prev=x

return ''.join((seqA, '\n', ''.join(['|'.rjust(x) for x in relative_similarity]), '\n', seqB, '\n', 'Score: ', str(score)))
```

Comment: They already are printed relative to the previous bar position.
Look at example: add this line `return similarity` at the end of method's code, instead this `return ''.join((seqA, '\n', ''.join(['|'.rjust(x) for x in similarity]), '\n', seqB, '\n', 'Score: ', str(score)))`. This will return the **similarity** list with it's values, so for `print pairwiseScore("ATTCGT", "ATCTAT"), '\n', '\n', pairwiseScore("GATAAATCTGGTCT", "CATTCATCATGCAA")` it will be `[0, 1, 5]` and `[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 10]`. Every _next_ bar will be positioned in accordance with corresponding number _relative to previous bar_.

Comment: @spaffy: I've added some code that may help explain what i'm saying.

Comment: Yeah, it helped, but now i must struggle with 3rd test case ( `pairwiseScore('CATTCATCATGCAA', 'GATAAATCTGGTCT')` ), which don't accept the solution, but should to.

Answer (score 1):

So, thanks to [Vaughn Cato](https://stackoverflow.com/users/951890/vaughn-cato), i came to the solution. Using your few lines of code, my method finally worked, but didn't passed last test case -> [image]

that was the code:

```
def pairwiseScore(seqA, seqB):

    prev = -1
    score = 0
    length = len(seqA)
    similarity = []
    relative_similarity = []

    for x in xrange(length):

        if seqA[x] == seqB[x]:
            if (x >= 1) and (seqA[x - 1] == seqB[x - 1]):
                score += 3
                similarity.append(x)
            else:
                score += 1
                similarity.append(x)                
        else:
            score -= 1

    for x in similarity:

        relative_similarity.append(x - prev)
        prev = x

    return ''.join((seqA, '\n', ''.join(['|'.rjust(x) for x in relative_similarity]), '\n', seqB, '\n', 'Score: ', str(score)))
```

So i modified a bit your example, and made this:

```
def pairwiseScore(seqA, seqB):

    score = 0
    bars = [str(' ') for x in seqA] #create a list filled with number of spaces equal to length of seqA string. It could be also seqB, because both are meant to have same length
    length = len(seqA)
    similarity = []

    for x in xrange(length):

        if seqA[x] == seqB[x]: #check if for every index 'x', corresponding character is same in both seqA and seqB strings
            if (x >= 1) and (seqA[x - 1] == seqB[x - 1]): #if 'x' is greater than or equal to 1 and characters under the previous index, were same in both seqA and seqB strings, do..
                score += 3
                similarity.append(x)
            else:
                score += 1
                similarity.append(x)                
        else:
            score -= 1

    for x in similarity:
        bars[x] = '|' #for every index 'x' in 'bars' list, replace space with '|' (pipe/vertical bar) character 

    return ''.join((seqA, '\n', ''.join(bars), '\n', seqB, '\n', 'Score: ', str(score)))
```

And this code passess all test cases in s3-q11 exercise. Sooo, i think i got the solution and i'm done.

Thanks and cheers :)